# How to send session data from middleware to layout?

Tags: laravel, middleware

I have middleware:

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isStudent() )
    {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('/');

}
```

I woould like to send data to my layout with redirect, I tryed to do like this:

```
$errors = ['You don't have permission, this side is ony for teachers']
return redirect('/login')->with('errors', $errors);
```

But It doesn't work, My layout doesn't see this.

This is my layout:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 @if (session('errors'))
        <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger">
            Wystąpiły następujące błędy:<br/>
            <ul>
                @foreach(session('errors') as $error)
                    <li>{!!$error!!}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif

    @yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how is your view looks like?

Comment: I changed my post and added my layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you can do. use `session()->flash('error','your Message')`

In your view you can do this like this

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
 if ( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isStudent() )
{
    return $next($request);
}

session()->flash('error','your Message')

return redirect('/');

}
```

then show this session in your views.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing sth wrong I think... 
My routing looks like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'student']], function () {
Route::get('/subjects', 'PanelController@showSubjects');
}

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'teacher']], function () {
Route::get('/teachers', 'PanelController@showClasses');
```

My fmiddleware function handle is excatly how You suggest, in my view like this:

```
@if (session('error'))
        <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger">
            <ul>
                    <li>{{session('error')}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
@endif
```

Still I can't see this message in my layout, when I login as a student, and go to site for example /teachers, there is no error, that access only for teachers... 
I don;t add nothing to my controllers? only middleware and view?

Comment: before `@if` I think you can check the data has passed with `{{dd(session()->all())}}`

Comment: Because if use `redirect('/login')->with('errors', $errors)` it should passed to that route

Comment: Only ma middleware auth redirect to /login, but I want to check the second middleware ( here student ) and if it is not student then I want redirect "/" and show error, that you are not authorized to access there, nothing works for now :(